# Layered architecture by Zenject's DiContainers with flat GameObjectContext hierarchy

Tags: zenject

Previous question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932959/dicontainers-layers)

In my application I have three layers:

- Data (Entities and Data Access Objects)
- Model (Managers)
- Presentation (Views)

[image]

How can I setup `Game Object Context` that `Model layer` will include all `Data layer` dependencies and `Presentation` layer will include all `Model`&`Data layers` dependencies?

Is there any way to set *parent component* for `Game Object Context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a GameObjectContext by right clicking in the Scene Hierarchy and selecting `Zenject -> GameObjectContext`.  You can add one for data, model, and presentation.  Then you just have to set the transform parents up the same way you want the container parents to be.  From your description I think you probably want it like this:

[image]

Then you can add each installer by attaching a MonoInstaller to each context.  You an also do all this dynamically using a FromSubContainerResolve inside a SceneContext installer as well, if you prefer.

Comment: I got it. Is there any way to implement it in the 'flat' way? Logically, the application layers should not be nested, they must be in the same plane.

Comment: @Alexandr not currently no, but that would be a good feature request to add to the git repo.  We could potentially add an optional "Parent Context" field in the inspector of GameObjectContext to support that kind of thing

Comment: @SteveVermeulen Narrator: unfortunately, they never did.